# Can we use SF Symbol on Android device in Jetpack Compose project?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, sf-symbols

I am creating a project and using **Swift** for iOS, **Jetpack Compose** for Android. But icons on Android ([Material+Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Round:grid_view:)) are difference with iOS. So I would like to use **[SF Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/)** of iOS for Android.

I researched and did not find any result for this.

Please anybody can help me out!

Comment: I'd recommend against it.  In general, Android users don't want their apps to look like an iOS port-  they want it to look like an Android app.  You will lose users for it.  You're better off either going with platform specific icons or platform neutral ones (a separate set of icons altogether from each).

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank for your recommended. Your idea is make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this is what I have done to copy ANY SF Symbol into and Android-compatible XML file. First, you need a good example of an android XML file. Download an Android icon from Google's Material Icons Font page [here](https://fonts.google.com/icons).

- On the right, you can prep the icon to be a certain weight, grade, and size
- Select any icon
- In the box that appears on the right, choose "Android"
- Select "Download" to get it on you computer

[Download from Google Fonts Material Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdhiS.png)

You will use this file as the XML representing the SF Symbol, so rename it to whatever you want it to be. Look at the XML file, to get the dimensions. You need these dimensions to export the icon from SF Symbols. **Notice the value of "android:viewportWidth", which is 960, in this example.**

```
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="960"
    android:viewportHeight="960"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M796,839L533,576Q503,602 463.04,616.5Q423.08,631 378,631Q269.84,631 194.92,556Q120,481 120,375Q120,269 195,194Q270,119 376.5,119Q483,119 557.5,194Q632,269 632,375.15Q632,418 618,458Q604,498 576,533L840,795L796,839ZM377,571Q458.25,571 515.13,513.5Q572,456 572,375Q572,294 515.13,236.5Q458.25,179 377,179Q294.92,179 237.46,236.5Q180,294 180,375Q180,456 237.46,513.5Q294.92,571 377,571Z"/>
</vector>
```

Now go to SF Symbols and select the icon you want to use in Android. Right-click and choose "Copy Image As..." and enter the value from "android:viewportWidth". This will put the XML data in your clipboard. Paste it into a text editor.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Generator: Apple Native CoreSVG 175.5-->
<!DOCTYPE svg
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1147.97" height="558.281">
 <g>
  <rect height="558.281" opacity="0" width="1147.97" x="0" y="0"/>
  <path d="M921.562 395.625C953.906 394.688 981.094 367.969 981.094 335.625C981.094 302.812 953.906 275.156 921.562 275.156C889.688 275.156 862.031 302.812 862.031 335.625C862.031 367.969 889.688 396.094 921.562 395.625ZM147.188 553.125L1000.78 553.125C1098.75 553.125 1147.97 504.375 1147.97 407.812L1147.97 144.844C1147.97 48.75 1098.75 0 1000.78 0L147.188 0C48.75 0 0 48.2812 0 144.844L0 407.812C0 504.844 48.75 553.125 147.188 553.125ZM148.125 477.656C101.25 477.656 75.4688 452.812 75.4688 404.062L75.4688 149.062C75.4688 100.312 101.25 75.4688 148.125 75.4688L999.844 75.4688C1046.25 75.4688 1072.5 100.312 1072.5 149.062L1072.5 404.062C1072.5 452.812 1046.25 477.656 999.844 477.656ZM1105.31 211.875L1105.31 150.469L43.5938 150.469L43.5938 211.875Z" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0.85"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

[Copy Image As... out of SF Symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJtQf.png)

Now copy the quoted section `<path d=` from the SF Symbol. In my example, it starts at `M921.562` and ends with `211.875Z`. Ignore anything else from the SF Symbol XML. Copy that entire path and paste it into the Android XML file. Then use the Android XML as a resource in Android Studio.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I need to update this slightly. When you "Copy Image As..." out of SF Symbols, don't blindly accept the 960 point size. Once you paste the SVG XML, look at the section `<rect height="xxx" width="xxx">` and make sure both of these numbers are as close to 960 as possible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).